# Eclipse Default JRE Preference Installed JRE Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse

I went to the Preference of Eclipse and changed the default JRE to the Java SE 8, and also changed the Compiler settings of Eclipse to be 1.8 JDK compliance. I even removed the other JREs.

However, when I import a project, as you can see from the Project Explorer, the project name is "SpringService", somehow the JRE System Library is JavaSE-1.6 and they are still using 1.6 as default!

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Otherwise every new project I have to manually go to the properties and change it manually! Hate it!

[image]

This post might be relevant to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896487/eclipse-default-jre-for-newly-created-imported-projects) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your *Installed JREs* preference, you want to select the root directory of a full Java Development Kit installation, not just a bare JRE installation. Eclipse needs access to the supporting libraries that are bundled with a full JDK, but absent from a base JRE install.

Also, if you are importing a project, do you mean that you are importing an existing, pre-configured Eclipse project? Or just the directory structure that contains the source code? If you are importing an existing Eclipse project, it may have already been set up with project-specific settings (it's hard to give advice with being able to poke around in the settings).

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin section in the pom.xml to see if it contains the following entry.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will overwrite the default preference. A lot of maven project archetype uses 1.6. Just change them to 1.8 and do a Maven->Update Project.

Answer (score 0):

U can you 'Build Path' on the project ,then remove the jre1.6, add  the  user libiary .